# SignalR Host No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, websocket, signalr

so currently i have a SignalR hub and an ASP API in the same project, all works fine and well ofcourse, however putting it onto the remote it'll give errors while connecting:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (--remoteIp--:80)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The api does work, just not the SignalR Hub

Do i have to disable something firewall wise, or is there anything i have to do?

server is Linux, Nginx.  asp is currently proxy routed and is HTTP

Comment: "onto the remote" is very little information. You'd need to provide much more information about the host machines so we can even try to guess what could go wrong.